# Linux kernel support of old(er) Radeon GPUs

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, gpu, radeon

I have a Radeon RX 6700XT and it works flawlessly in Linux.

I am looking at getting an older Radeon card and was wondering what is the support for something like a Rx 460.

Is it native as my beefy 6700XT?